# Better keyboard interrupt detection for this threaded Spinner class

Tags: python, exception, spinner, keyboardinterrupt

Ok, I've wrote this class based in a bunch of others Spinner classes that I've googled in Google Code Search.

It's working as intended, but I'm looking for a better way to handle KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit exceptions. Is there better approaches?

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
import sys
import threading

class Spinner(threading.Thread):
    '''Represent a random work indicator, handled in a separate thread'''

    # Spinner glyphs
    glyphs = ('|', '/', '-', '\\', '|', '/', '-')
    # Output string format
    output_format = '%-78s%-2s'
    # Message to output while spin
    spin_message = ''
    # Message to output when done
    done_message = ''
    # Time between spins
    spin_delay = 0.1

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Spinner constructor'''
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.daemon = True
        self.__started = False
        self.__stopped = False
        self.__glyphs = itertools.cycle(iter(self.glyphs))

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        '''Convenient way to run a routine with a spinner'''
        self.init()
        skipped = False

        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            skipped = True
        finally:
            self.stop(skipped)

    def init(self):
        '''Shows a spinner'''
        self.__started = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        '''Spins the spinner while do some task'''
        while not self.__stopped:
            self.spin()

    def spin(self):
        '''Spins the spinner'''
        if not self.__started:
            raise NotStarted('You must call init() first before using spin()')

        if sys.stdin.isatty():
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            sys.stdout.write(self.output_format % (self.spin_message,
                                                   self.__glyphs.next()))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(self.spin_delay)

    def stop(self, skipped=None):
        '''Stops the spinner'''
        if not self.__started:
            raise NotStarted('You must call init() first before using stop()')

        self.__stopped = True
        self.__started = False

        if sys.stdin.isatty() and not skipped:
            sys.stdout.write('\b%s%s\n' % ('\b' * len(self.done_message),
                                           self.done_message))
            sys.stdout.flush()

class NotStarted(Exception):
    '''Spinner not started exception'''
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time

    # Normal example
    spinner1 = Spinner()
    spinner1.spin_message = 'Scanning...'
    spinner1.done_message = 'DONE'
    spinner1.init()
    skipped = False

    try:
        time.sleep(5)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        skipped = True
    finally:
        spinner1.stop(skipped)

    # Callable example
    spinner2 = Spinner()
    spinner2.spin_message = 'Scanning...'
    spinner2.done_message = 'DONE'
    spinner2(time.sleep, 5)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need to worry about catching [`SystemExit`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) as it is raised by `sys.exit()`. You might want to catch it to clean up some resources just before your program exits.

The other way to catch [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) is to register a signal handler to catch `SIGINT`. However for your example using `try..except` makes more sense, so you're on the right track.

A few minor suggestions:

- Perhaps rename the `__call__` method to `start`, to make it more clear you're starting a job.
- You might also want to make the Spinner class reusable by attaching a new thread within the `start` method, rather than in the constructor.
- Also consider what happens when the user hits CTRL-C for the current spinner job -- can the next job be started, or should the app just exit?
- You could also make the `spin_message` the first argument to `start` to associate it with the task about to be run.

For example, here is how someone might use Spinner:

```
dbproc = MyDatabaseProc()
spinner = Spinner()
spinner.done_message = 'OK'
try:
    spinner.start("Dropping the database", dbproc.drop, "mydb")
    spinner.start("Re-creating the database", dbproc.create, "mydb")
    spinner.start("Inserting data into tables", dbproc.populate)
    ...
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # stop the currently executing job
    spinner.stop()
    # do some cleanup if needed..
    dbproc.cleanup()
```